# Pass variable value from Text field to variable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an implementation of class similar to this:

```
-(id)initWithLogin:(NSString *)_login password:(NSString *)_password{

if(( self = [super init])){

    login = _login;
    password = _password;

}

return self;

}
```

and my question is - how to init new object with value from `TextField` (I know how to alloc and init objects, but don't know how to pass values from TextField to this method)?

I'm very beginner of objective-c so every step-by-step solutions will be appreciated (or links for related articles/video tutorial).

Comment: get value from textField in this way: NSString *string = yourTextField.text

Comment: ok, thank You, can you tell me how/where I can define id/name for TextField (in your example it is yourTextField - where i Can define this value)?

Comment: where your facing the problem now ? accessing the initWithLogin method are getting the login and password string out side of the method ?

Comment: please accept any of the answers if your problem get solved else edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this -

For getting Password -

```
NSString *password = txtPassword.text;
```

For getting Login Id -

```
NSString *loginID = txtLoginId.text;
```

And now,call the above method and pass those variables.

Hope this will help you.Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok, thank You - this should really help me. Another question: how i can define that txtPassword will reffer to my textField value?

Comment: Welcome.You can refer me for any query. :)

Comment: create the iBOutlet from your storyboard to .h file and give the name as txtPassword, to create IBOutlet simply control-drag from your storyboard viewcontroller to your .h file and give the name

Answer (score 0):

simply pass the `UITextField.text` value to `-(id)initWithLogin:(NSString *)_login password:(NSString *)_password` method e.g..

suppose you have two textfields one for login and other for password then create the object and pass the values

```
YourClassName *class = [[YourClassName alloc] initWithLogin:loginTextField.text password:passowrdTextField.text];
```